# Connecting with SQL Server Management Studio (Remote)

Tags: sql-server, firewall, rdp

All right, here's my problem:
I have set up a sql server 2014 on a windows server 2012 R2.

If I'm connecting through the local network just with the ip, everything works fine.
Now we need to access it outside the local network.

I've tried following:
ipaddress\SQLEXPRESS,1433
ipaddress\SQLEXPRESS
ipaddress
ipaddress,1433
tcp:ipaddress\SQLEXPRESS
tcp:ipaddress\SQLEXPRESS,1433
And everything failed.

My guess is the firewall (ASA, managed with ASDM 6.3), but I have not the slightest idea how to configure it or just to resolve my problem (Googling and searching through some posts didn't help).

Does anybody have an idea or a solution?
And if anything more is needed I'm more than happy to provide it.

Best thanks
Simon

Comment: Do you have public IP addresses or private ones behind NAT?

Comment: From your outside interface you have to tell it when it comes in on that port to send it over to your SQL Server machine. I would think you'd configure the app to connect to it as `ipaddress\SQLEXPRESS,1433` from your app server or else have DB Alias setup to resolve to DNS name. A little more detail would be helpful such as (per Sven) public (or private) IP behind NAT, connect an app with those values in some config file, etc. You'd also need tell Windows FW to allow that traffic on that port in too assuming it's enabled.

Comment: I don't surely know if it was a public or private, but we had to add a static NAS-rule which did the trick. Thank you very much for your input

Comment: Yes, if you want the PUBLIC Internet to be able to come into your server, then you'd require a public IP address on your network to route it to it. A simple and basic analogy would be ------------->`street address`.`city`.`state`.`zip code`, would be a like `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` which is a PUBLIC IP address analogy and you can get postal mail to it. Inside your house `living room`.`bedroom`.`restroom`.`kitchen`, the outside mail isn't delivered to these locations unless you get it from the mailbox and take it inside to the rooms you want it to go to this is PRIVATE IP address analogy. @user1611719

Comment: @user1611719 So with the NAT rule you added, you said if it comes to my public IP address (postal mailbox) on this port number, then send that over to this private IP (these rooms inside my house) which will be listening on that port to accept and do whatever with, etc. I'm not a network guru but that's the basic of how that works if it clarifies any.  It's just pointers to different IP addresses on different ports routing public and private IP addresses, etc. and in which direction (inbound or outbound) per interface or configurable physical network ports on the devices.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you should do is seperate a network connectivity issue, use a tool like telnet to attempt to reach port 1433 on the SQL Server host, such as:

```
telnet ipaddress 1433
```

If you get a connection refused error, it is likely that SQL Server isn't listening as intended, if the connection times out there is a connectivity problem between your two points and potentially the firewall is at fault.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your reply. We found some analysing-tool and had to insert a NAT-Roule on the firewall for port 1433 to fix this.